# How to paste xml to C++ (Tinyxml)

Tags: c++, xml, tinyxml

I'm currently working on a project in C++ where I need to read some things from a xml file, I've figured out that tinyxml seams to be the way to go, but I still don't know exactly how to do.
Also my xml file is a little tricky, because it looks a little different for every user that needs to use this.

The xml file I need to read looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<cloud_xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx xmlns:d="http://www.kuju.com/TnT/2003/Delta" d:version="1.0">
    <cCareerModel d:id="154964152">
        <ScenarioCareer>
            <cScenarioCareer d:id="237116344">
                <IsCompleted d:type="cDeltaString">CompletedSuccessfully</IsCompleted>
                <BestScore d:type="sInt32">0</BestScore>
                <LastScore d:type="sInt32">0</LastScore>
                <ID>
                    <cGUID>
                        <UUID>
                            <e d:type="sUInt64">5034713268864262327</e>
                            <e d:type="sUInt64">2399721711294842250</e>
                        </UUID>
                        <DevString d:type="cDeltaString">0099a0b7-e50b-45de-8a85-85a12e864d21</DevString>
                    </cGUID>
                </ID>
            </cScenarioCareer>
        </ScenarioCareer>
        <MD5 d:type="cDeltaString"></MD5>
    </cCareerModel>
</cloud_xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx>
```

Now the goal of this program is to be able to insert some string (via. a variable) and serch for the corresponding "cScenarioCarrer d:id" and read the "IsComplete" and the "BestScore".

Those strings later need to be worked with in my program, but that I can handle.

My questions here are

A. How do I go by searching for a specific "cScenarioCareer" ID

B. How do I paste the "IsComplete" and "BestScore" into some variables in my program.

Note: The xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx string is unique for every user, so keep in mind it can be anything.

If anyone out there would like to help me, I'd be very graceful, thank you.

PS. I'd like to have some kind of understanding for what I'm doing here, all though "paste this code into your program" answers are acceptable, I think it would be much better if you can tell me how and why it works.

Comment: It sounds like what you really want is [TinyXPath](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tinyxpath/?_test=beta).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're doing this in C++ I'll make this example using the ticpp interface to
TinyXml that available at ticpp.googlecode.com.

Assumptions:

- A given xml file will contain one `<cloud>` tag and multiple
  `<cCareerModel>` tags.
- Each `<cCareerModel>` contains a single `<ScenarioCareer>` tag which in turn contains a single `<cScenarioCareer>` tag
- You've parsed the xml file into a TiXmlDocument called xmlDoc
- You don't need to examine the data type attributes
- You don't mind using exceptions

I'll also assume that you have a context variable somewhere containing a pointer to the
`<cloud>` tag, like so:

```
ticpp::Element* cloud = xmlDoc.FirstChildElement("cloud");
```

Here's a function that will locate the ticpp::Element for the cScenarioCareer with
the given ID.

```
ticpp::Element* findScenarioCareer(const std::string& careerId)
{
  try
  {
    // Declare an iterator to access all of the cCareerModel tags and construct an
    // end iterator to terminate the loop
    ticpp::Iterator<ticpp::Element> careerModel;
    const ticpp::Iterator<ticpp::Element> modelEnd = careerModel.end();

    // Loop over the careerModel tags
    for (careerModel = cloud->FirstChildElement() ; careerModel != modelEnd ;
         ++careerModel)
    {
      // Construct loop controls to access careers
      ticpp::Iterator<ticpp::Element> career;
      const ticpp::Iterator<ticpp::ELement> careerEnd = career.end();

      // Loop over careers
      for (career = careerModel->FirstChildElement("ScenarioCareer").FirstChildElement() ; 
           career != careerEnd ; ++career)
      {
        // If the the d:id attribute value matches then we're done
        if (career->GetAttributeOrDefault("d:id", "") == careerId)
          return career;
      }
    }
  }
  catch (const ticpp::Exception&)
  {
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Then to get at the information you want you'd do something like:

```
std::string careerId = "237116344";
std::string completion;
std::string score;
ticpp::Element* career = findScenarioCareer(careerId);
if (career)
{
  try
  {
    completion = career->FirstChildElement("IsCompleted")->GetText();
    score = career->FirstChildElement("BestScore")->GetText();
  }
  catch (const ticpp::Exception&)
  {
    // Handle missing element condition
  }
}
else
{
  // Not found
}
```

Naturally I haven't compiled or tested any of this, but it should give you the idea.